# $\lambda $- geodesic convexity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, optimal-transport

Let $(X,d)$ be a geodesic space, suppose $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is geodesically $\lambda$ convex with $\lambda >0$, that is for all $x,y \in X$ there exists a constant speed geodesic $\gamma$ from $x$ to $y$ such that for all $s\in [0,1]$
$$
g(\gamma_s) \leq s g(x) + (1-s) g(y) -\frac{\lambda}{2}s(1-s)d(x,y)^2
$$
Let $x_0$ be the unique minimizer of $g$. Show that $\forall x$
$$
g(x) \geq g(x_0) + \frac{\lambda}{2}d(x,x_0)^2
$$

EDIT: thanks for the comment.
Honestly I did not do much because I was stuck from the beginning, since I had no idea how to use the geodesic property. I just picked a geodesic between $x$ and $x_0$ and tried to plug in the property but did not see how that could help!
Any hint or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose your geodesic with $\gamma_{0}=x_{0}$ and $\gamma_{1}=x$. Since $x_{0}$ is minimal we have
\begin{equation}
0=\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}g(\gamma_{s}).
\end{equation}
Then, using your first inequality it follows
\begin{equation}
0=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}(g(\gamma_{h})-g(x_{0}))\le\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(hg(x)+(1-h)g(x_{0})-\frac{\lambda}{2}h(1-h)d^{2}(x,x_{0})-g(x_{0})\right)
\end{equation}
which yields the claim.

Comment: That's essentially correct, but in general you only have $0\leq \liminf_{h\to 0}(g(\gamma_h)-g(x_0))$ - think of $g(x)=|x|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for example.